# Detect if user has got any copied content

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

I want to detect if the user has some copied content and if so use that to fill up a `UITextField` if the user wants to.

Is there anyone that's found out a simple solution? Really don't know the right way so find it..

So the question is pretty much to detect if the user has some copy to paste in.

[Truecaller Image Example](http://i58.tinypic.com/2m9s3n.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check content of clipboard via

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine! Will put up some code how I used it! @jakub-vano